# How to use multiple wordpress websites in wamp?

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I installed Wamp and already developing a Wordpress site in localhost.But i want to setup another Wordpress site in Wamp server localhost.I searched for solutions for this,but remains unsolved because solutions posted by them are old and outdated and some solutions i tried gives me errors.

I am using Wamp 3.0.6(current latest version) and Wordpress 4.8(current latest version) on Windows 10.

I created my first site and named it 'mysite' and is situated in C:\wamp\www\mysite.How can i create another site calling it 'mysite1' in Wamp server?Also what about MySql database setup for the new site(mysite1).I use database named 'sitedata' for my first site(mysite).Should i use same database(sitedata) or can i create new database for 'mysite1'?

I access Wordpress site on Wamp by going to http://localhost/mysite/ in Chrome.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson@Shadow Its OK guys,i found the solution in another site.Should i put that link here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just create another folder in wamp - install your new wordpress there.

So go to your files C:\wamp\www\ - create C:\wamp\www\mysite2

put the installer there.

go into your phpmyadmin and create a new database.

access your new site/folder and follow the installers instructions.

you will nowhave two different sites, with two different databases.

Comment: It is better to create a Virtual Host for wach of your projects. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Answer (score 0):

Just create another folder in wamp - install your new WordPress.

So go to your files `C:\wamp\www\` - create `C:\wamp\www\mysite2` (you can use any name you want)

Put the installer of WordPress there.

Go into your PHPMyAdmin and create a new database.

Access your new site/folder and follow the instructions of the installer.

Now you will have two different sites, with two different databases.